# Generic limitation in F#

Tags: f#, generics

Until now, I had a class like this one:

```
type C<'a when 'a :> A> (...)
```

But now I created a new type B:

```
type B (...) =
    inherit A()
```

But I don't want C to support B, and this doesn't compile:

```
type C<'a when 'a :> A and not 'a :> B> (...)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't and shouldn't. If B is an A, then C should handle it. If it's reasonable for C not to be able to handle B, then B shouldn't derive from A. Otherwise you're effectively breaking [Liskov's Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (or at least a variant of the same).

When you declare that B inherits from A, you're saying that it can be used as an A. If that's not the case, you shouldn't be using inheritance.

Comment: even if you could, it would still be broken by casting B to A beforehand anyway.

Comment: I know that it is wrong by OOP standards, but I have a complicated scenario in which I use inheritance to inherit members, but B isn't really an A. Except in those few cases in which I use A's members - it is not A.

Comment: @Ramon: Unsurprisingly, when you abuse inheritance you'll run up against problems like this. I'd urge you to reconsider your design.

Comment: Correct me if I abuse again, but I think I will add a third base class which will contain the "members" so both A and B will inherit it.

Comment: @Ramon: That certainly sounds like an improvement, if not actually ideal - it's hard to say more without knowing details of your exact situation of course.